# How to write a function output to a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to write an output from a function to a text file, but unsure how to do this. I know how I can do this with a variable, and this works fine. However, I am unable to work this out with a function.

Any advice?

```
def test():
    device = "PC"
    print(device + " This is an example")
    print("Writing to output")
test()
```

**Example 1**

```
def test():

    f = open("newfile.txt", "a")

    device = "PC"
    print(device + " This is an example")
    print("Writing to output")

    f.write()
    f.close()
```

**Issue**

TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

**Example 2**

```
def test():

    f = open("newfile.txt", "a")

    device = "PC"
    print(device + " This is an example")
    print("Writing to output")

    f.write(test())
    f.close()
```

**Issue**

Newfile.txt was created, however no data in the file.

Comment: Print outputs to the console, it is not the output of a function.

Comment: I think you can read the documentation for how to call those functions properly and Google "python write to file" just as well as I can. This is not a tutorial or debugging site.

Answer (score 1):

```
def test():
    device = "PC"
    print("writing to output")
    return device + " This is an example"

with open("newfile.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(test())
```

Answer (score 0):

In first example you don't put anything in write function
Just put what you want

```py
def test():
    f = open("newfile.txt", "a")
    device = "PC"
    f.write(device + " This is an example")
    f.write("Writing to output")
    f.close()
```

In second function, You are trying to call test function in test function. It is possible but it has no interest here.

If you want to write the output of a function, you must return this value to use it

```py
def test():
    result = ''
    device = "PC"
    result = device + " This is an example"
    result += "Writing to output"

    return result

f = open("newfile.txt", "a")
f.write(test()) 
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File_object.write(argument)
```

takes one argument inside the parenthesis `f.write(device)`

You are missing with the argument in you 1st part on answer which should be the text that you wanna write into new file.

Complete code:-

```
def test():
    device = "PC"
    print("writing to output")
    return device + " This is an example"


f = open("newfile.txt", "a")
f.write(test())
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it:

```
def test(filename, device):
    print("Writing to output")
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(device+" This is an example")

def main():
    test("file.txt", "PC")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hope it's usable. :-)